# Can "-ish" be used for any nouns?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases, nouns, word-form

I am a Japanese student.

I know some words that end with "ish" such as girlish and Turkish. 
If I say "His learning style is Obamaish", does this make sense?

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer:

**Yes**. English permits you to use suffixes such as *-ish, -esque, -ian*, and even *-like* to turn words – including proper names – into adjectives. See, for example, [this headline](http://www.scmp.com/news/asia/article/1466535/indias-likely-next-leader-modi-seen-implementing-thatcher-reforms):

> India's likely next leader Modi seen implementing ***Thatcher-like*** reforms

#### Additional commentary:

- I'm not sure how Obama learns, so your example sentence would confuse me without any additional context. Just because we *can* invent new words like these doesn't mean we should do so recklessly.
- Make sure you use the right prefix. For example, *Obamaish* would mean *sort of like Obama's style*, while *Obamaesque* would mean *just like Obama's style*. See [this cartoon caption](http://imgc-cn.artprintimages.com/images/P-473-488-90/60/6062/49ED100Z/posters/william-hamilton-he-s-coming-across-as-reaganish-but-not-reaganesque-new-yorker-cartoon.jpg) for an interesting example highlighting the subtle difference:

> *"He's coming across as Reaganish but not Reaganesque."*

- Some of these words become standard nomenclature, (e.g., [*Keynesian economics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynesian_economics)), but we don't have to wait until someone else uses a word before we do. Someone has to be first. That said, non-native speakers might want to do so with care.

Comment: I completely agree.  I would also say, however, that the acceptability of these terms can be considered to tiptoe a bit into the grey area... meaning that native speakers will generally know what they mean but their propriety can be questionable.

Comment: The cartoon is great! But isn't its point that _ish, -esque, -ian_ and the like are mostly vague suffixes for off-the-cuff talk, and don't really have any precise meaning? The humor, as I understand it, is that some people foolishly try to use them as a precise way to talk about hazy things (and that these pseudo-precise usages are _de rigueur_ only among the most extreme fashion- and trend-followers).

Answer (score 0):

The suffix “-ish” has its own entry in many dictionaries. I’ve picked one I like:

> **-ish**
>   suffix
>
> 1. of or belonging to a nationality or group: *Scottish*
> 2. (often derogatory) having the manner or qualities of; resembling: *slavish, prudish, boyish*
> 3. somewhat; approximately: *yellowish, sevenish*
> 4. concerned or preoccupied with: *bookish*
>
> <sub>Source: [dictionary.com definitions for *-ish*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ish)</sub>

Your example doesn’t fit any of the above categories particularly well. I suppose it’s close to the second sense, but that one isn’t used much to form new words. Usually, if someone’s forming an *[ad-hoc](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc)* adjective with “-ish”, they’re going to mean it in the 3rd sense. *The sky was yellowish at sixish today.*

Luckily, there are many ways to create adjectives out of nouns. The easiest, most broadly understandable way is to add “-like” to the end of the noun. Here’s “-like” in a dictionary:

> **-like**
>
> 1. a suffixal use of like in the formation of adjectives (*childlike; lifelike*), sometimes hyphenated.
>
> <sub>Source: [dictionary.com definitions for *-like*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-like?s=t)</sub>

Though he’s not known for a particular learning style, I think “Obama-like” is easier to understand than “Obama-ish”. You can also consider [“-esque”](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-esque), but that has more to do with expressive styles.

Answer (score 0):

Ryo you can do that. However, you would have to make sure that the people with whom you are using this word:

1. are aware of the characteristics of Obama's learning style;
2. are aware of the characteristic of "his" working style (whoever "his" happens to be);
3. and are able to make the connection between the two working styles through the shares characteristics.

In your case, when you add the suffix ***-ish*** to a word, you do one of three things:

1. form an adjective (*girlish*)
2. having the qualities or characteristics of a noun (*British*)
3. to mean somewhat (*greenish*)

Your sentence is an example of 1 (in the second list). However, because it is not an "accepted" word, and even if the context of characteristics is clear, you should put the word in quotation marks.

One example I have seen is in UK political discourse where former prime minister Tony Blair has a noted style with obvious characteristics. So instead of using everyone of those adjectives to describe the characteristics, they are all combined into a new word "Blairish". This is used to describe someone, especially in the Labour party, who has/shares these similar characteristics as Tony Blair.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, in the sense that the face meaning of the word would be understood (though as pointed out above, it should clearly imply a specific point of comparison in order to be effective).

When you use "-ish" this way, you should do it with the understanding that you're coining a new word others might find silly, not just applying a rule. Silliness is fine in most contexts if it gets your point across.